# Stock Price Question

Tags: normal-distribution

Can anyone show me how to answer this please?

A stock has beta of 2.0 and stock specific daily volatility of 0.04. Suppose that yesterday’s closing price was 95 and today the market goes up by 3%. What’s the probability of today’s closing price being at least 98?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @LouisMarascio Feels like it! But no it is not.

Comment: If it is not homework, perhaps you want to share some more information, else why not just go with this? 1-pnorm((<end>-<start>)/100,mean=E(r_stock),sd=(<beta>*<vola>))

Comment: @RndmSymbl Could you show me the worked out numbers step by step pls.

Comment: @ManInMoon this question is better asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339572/stock-behaviour-probability And I have improved the answer there.